# Service Bus for Windows server - creation of namespace by REST API

Tags: servicebus

Does it possible to create a namespace via REST API in Service Bus for Windows Server? I found a way to communicate with it (e.g. sending messages) but I was not able to figure out how to create a namespace similar way.
I found in few sources  that API for Azure service bus and for this one are much similar. So there is an API reference - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh780717.aspx. And this document has the CreateNamespace method - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856303.aspx
But it is looks like Azure-only thing and I had no luck implementing it with service bus for windows.

I know, that there is a way to create it with powershell commands, but for now I am looking for other ways to do it.